# mrtg straight graphing

Tags: mrtg

How to correct this type of straight graph..., When my devices once reboot i begin to get the attached type of straight graphs.. Kindly help.

[image]

mrtg create this type of straight graph when device reboots.. and when device reboots snmp starts automatically.. is there no way to make this correct?? or does not happen?

Answer (score 4):

A vague, short answer to a vague, short question: `snmpd` is probably not automatically starting during the server startup. Start `snmpd` at the server you are trying to graph.

Comment: JP is right; mrtg's usual response to "i can't get any new data" is "i'll keep on graphing the last data i did get", leading to straight-line graphs.  check that mrtg can in fact get up-to-date data from the device(s) in question, and if it can't, fix it.